# Non-scalar custom-defined metric in Tensorflow Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, metrics

It's my first question posted on StackOverflow ever, so be patient please and let me know if I should somehow improve my question : )

Let's say I want to compute a separate metric value for each class. Is there a way to use a custom-defined metric function in Tensorflow implementation of Keras which outputs non-scalar tensor? As an example: I've got a custom metric function `balanced_accuracy_per_class` returning tensor of shape `(1, 4)` and I feed it to `compile` method as shown below:

```
# Define some dummy data:
train_data = tf.constant([
    [0.2, 0.5, 0.1, 0.0, 5.2, 6.3],
    [0.4, 0.1, 0.8, 0.4, 6.4, 7.5],
])

train_labels = tf.constant([
    [1., 0., 0., 0.],
    [0., 1., 1., 0.],
])

val_data = tf.constant([
    [0.3, 0.4, 0.2, 0.1, 2.2, 4.3],
    [3.4, 3.1, 2.8, 1.4, 2.4, 5.5],
])

val_labels = tf.constant([
    [0., 1., 0., 1.],
    [1., 0., 0., 0.],
])

# Example dummy implementation.
def balanced_accuracy_per_class(y_true, y_pred):
    return tf.constant([0.0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6])

sgd = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=0.1, decay=0.000225, momentum=0.5)

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, input_shape=(6, )))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Activation('sigmoid'))

model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
          loss='mse',
          metrics=[balanced_accuracy_per_class])

model.fit(train_data, train_labels, epochs=3, steps_per_epoch=1)

evaluation_results = model.evaluate(val_data, val_labels, steps=1)
```

Both during training and evaluation phase the progress bar outputs metrics as a scalar (0.3 to be specific):

> Epoch 1/3
>
> 1/1 [==============================] - 0s 81ms/step - loss: 0.2392 - balanced_accuracy_per_class: 0.3000
>
> Epoch 2/3
>
> 1/1 [==============================] - 0s 0s/step - loss: 0.2367 - balanced_accuracy_per_class: 0.3000
>
> Epoch 3/3
>
> 1/1 [==============================] - 0s 997us/step - loss: 0.2350 - balanced_accuracy_per_class: 0.3000
>
> 1/1 [==============================] - 0s 53ms/step - loss: 0.4557 - balanced_accuracy_per_class: 0.3000

What i'd like to achieve is `model.evaluate` returning an array instead of a scalar for a given metric.

The docstring of model's [evaluate function](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.13/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py#L882) explicitly mentions "scalar or list of scalars", but maybe I'm missing something?

Thanks!